# how to make my ladder plc hidden ?I want to make it secret from other people?

Tags: plc, siemens, ladder-logic, simatic-net

if I want to create a ladder diagram on step7.after I want to make it secret from other people?

Answer (score 1):

you can *Know-how protection* and FB, FC or OB and assign a password.  All other people will need the password to access the code inside.
[image]